# Select every array item in column from every row postgres

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I have a table which looks like this:

```
Name | Data
-------------
Test1 | {"toasts": [{"type": "dark", "calories": "100"}, {"type": "white", "calories": "200"}, {"type": "gray", "calories": "300"}]}
"Test2" | {"toasts": [{"type": "white", "calories": "200"}]}
```

Data is an array of objects.

What I need is to select all array items in all rows:

```
Res
--------
{type: 'dark', calories: '100'}
{type: 'white', calories: '200'}
{type: 'gray', calories: '300'}
{type: 'white', calories: '200'}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is not a valid json data. It should rather be :

| Name | Data |
| --- | --- |
| Test1 | {"toasts": [{"type": "dark", "calories": 100}, {"type": "white", "calories": 200}, {"type": "gray", "calories": 300}]} |
| Test2 | {"toasts": [{"type": "white", "calories": 200}]} |

The query to get the expected result is :

```
SELECT jsonb_path_query(Data :: jsonb, '$.toasts[*]') AS res FROM my_table
```

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9d900xOh)

Comment: Thank you thats it. sorry JSON, thats  not an actual prod data, I compose it on the fly. will edit now.